# Wordpress Rewritten URL returns all posts, ignoring Elementor custom query

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, elementor

I have a portfolio page that displays customs posts "project" using the Elementor Pro Loop Grid widget and a custom query.I also added a rewrite rule. It all seems to work just fine, except:

**website.com/portfolio/?date=2022** returns posts published on 2022.

**website.com/portfolio/2022** returns all posts.

```
function custom_register_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'date';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_register_query_vars' );

function aesc_rewrite_date () {
    add_rewrite_rule('^(portfolio)/(\d{4})/?' , 'index.php?fecha=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'aesc_rewrite_date', 10, 0);
```

Custom query is:

```
 add_action( 'elementor/query/custom_query', function( $query ) {
    $query->set('post_type' , 'project');

    if ( isset( $_GET['fecha']) ) {
        //Check if year variable is set in query. Log if not.        
        $query->set('year' , $_GET['date']);
    }
});
```

I have reviewed both Wordpress `add_rewrite_rule()` and Elementor's Custom Queries documentation and cannot pinpoint the problem. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.